# Call script functions in page that uses of masterpage

Tags: javascript

How can I call functions by click a bottun or in onload of BodyContent
 where I use of masterpage?

Answer (score 0):

The same way as any other function (`function_name` followed by `(` then any arguments then `)`). The browser doesn't know things are separated out on the server, it only sees the combined page delivered to it.